# Reuse components with different Vuex stores in NuxtJS - Create dynamic/multiple VueX store instances

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuex

I have a [vue.js](/questions/tagged/vue.js)/[nuxt.js](/questions/tagged/nuxt.js) component in my UI that displays news based on a backend which can be queried with selectors (e.g. `news-type1`, `news-type2`).

I want to add a second instance of that component which uses exactly the same backend, but allows the user to use a few different selectors (e.g. `news-type3`, `news-type4`). The UI kinda works dashboard-like. Implementing that distinction in the `.vue` component file is no problem (just accept some props and display stuff conditionally to the user), but:

**How do I reuse the [vuex](/questions/tagged/vuex) store?** The code of the store for the new card stays exactly the same since the same backend is used. But I can't use the same **instance** of the store because the selectors and the loaded news should be stored per component and should not be shared between them. Surprisingly I haven't been able to find any easy solutions for that in nuxt. I thought this would be a common use case.

MWE for my use case:

```js
/** Vuex store in store/news.js **/

export const state = () => ({
  // per default only news-type1 is selected, but not news-type2. the user can change that in the UI
  currentSelectors: ['news-type1'], 
  news = [] // object array containing the fetched news
});

export const mutations = {
  // some very simple mutations for the stae
  setSelectors (state, data) {
    state.currentSelectors = data;
  },
  setNews (state, data) {
    state.news = data;
  }
}

export const actions = {
  // simplified get and commit function based on the currentSelectors
  async loadNews ({ commit, state }) {
    const news = await this.$axios.$get(`/api/news/${state.currentSelectors.join(',')}`);
    commit('setNews', news);
    // ... truncated error handling 
  },
  // Helper action. In comparison to the mutation with the same name, it also calls the load action
  async setSelectors ({ commit, dispatch }, selectors) {
    commit('setSelectors', selectors);
    dispatch('loadNews');
  },
};
```

In my `news-card.vue` I simply map the two states and call the two actions `loadNews` (initial load) and `setSelectors` (after user changes what news to show in the UI). This should stay the same in both instances of the card, it *just* should go to different store instances.

My current alternative would be to simply copy-paste the store code to a new file `store/news-two.js` and then using either that store or the original store depending on which prop is passed to my `news-card` component. For obvious reasons, that would be bad practice. Is there a better complicated alternative that works with nuxt?

All related questions I have found are only for Vue, not for nuxt vuex stores: [Need multiple instances of Vuex module for multiple Vue instances](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55272189/4026792) or [How to re-use component that should use unique vuex store instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58719210/4026792).

Comment: Have you found any solution so far @thomas?

Comment: @helle Unfortunately not. I've prioritized other things for now. But I'll keep looking for a way. If I should find a satisfiable solution that doesn't involve an ugly hack, I'll add that as an answer.